# UniversalViewerWithCustomQuery Where Clause using a QueryString Param

Tags: kentico

I would like to load a page with the UniversalViewerWithCustomQuery webpart using a query string parameter in the page URL:

Page URL w/ Query string parameter: **mysite\home\mypage.aspx?id=3**

My Content Queries that I have tried thus far:

> SELECT Top 1 ObjectID,Field1,Field2 FROM MyTable Where ObjectID = {%
>   QueryString.id %}

Get Error: *Incorrect syntax near '%'*. So then I tried:

> SELECT Top 1 ObjectID,Field1,Field2 FROM MyTable Where ##WHERE##

Content filter Where clause: ObjectID = {% QueryString.id %}

Get Error: *Invalid SQL query in property "wherecondition".*

I have also tried to use just a string {% '3' %} in place of the querystring parameter and get the same errors. I know I'm doing something wrong but cannot figure out what...

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Update 1

I moved all the SQL stuff into a custom stored proc using the Database objects app.  
Where is there an example of how to call the Stored Proc from my  UniversalViewerWithCustomQuery?

Update 2

To call, figured I'd try regular old TSQL and it worked:

> EXEC Proc_Custom_MyProc_MyProc

but when I try to call with a parameter I get the same errors as before!!!

> EXEC Proc_Custom_MyProc_MyProc @id = {% '2' %}

Comment: Please ensure your queries are not open to SQL injection; your examples look like they could be. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28with_Parameterized_Queries.29

Comment: Thanks for looking out. Not the final version, starting simple and working up.

Answer (score 0):

When you're entering the macro are you using the arrow to the left of the input box to enter it? Your condition should look like this:

```
ObjectId = {% QueryString.GetValue("id", 0) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below Query syntax :

> SELECT ##TOPN## ##COLUMNS## FROM MyTable Where ##WHERE##

Input parameters from web part

1. Select top N: 1
2. WHERE condition: ObjectID={% QueryString.GetValue("id", 0)#%} [Or {%id%}]
3. Columns: ObjectID,Field1,Field2